# Smooth real valued function on a Manifold

Tags: analysis

Let M be a smooth manifold . $f: M\rightarrow R$ be a real valued function. Show that if f is smooth at a point p in M , then f is smooth in a neighborhood of p in M.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Can I ask where you found this statement? Because I think it is false.

Comment: I don't remember the book name.

Comment: If you think It is useful, can you mark my answer, please?

Comment: Yeah , I found similar kind of question in the book of Riemann surfaces by Rick Miranda.

Answer (score 1):

I think your statement is not true. In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3062945/601797) you can find a function on a manifold ($\mathbb R$) which is smooth only in one point (the origin).